# Downloading files from Opa database

Tags: database, download, opa

I've saved a file using the Upload module into an Opa database.

Now I want to download theses files from the database. How can I do that ?

Any idea ?

Thanks,

kayhman

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your problem?

I suppose you already know how to retrieve a value from the database.
Then you just have to serve this file it this way:

```
url_parser = parser
  | "/file.pdf" -> Resource.binary(v,"application/pdf")
```

Read more about `Resource.binary` and `Resource.source here`:

http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.web.resource.resource.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.web.resource.Resource.binary

http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.web.resource.resource.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.web.resource.Resource.source